# Netbeans render unrecognized files as html

Tags: php, html, netbeans, formatting

I am using Netbeans and very happy with it. Unfortunately I am having a little problem with it that I cant seem to figure out. I am using Silverstripe CMS and it uses a templating system that syntactically is basically just a mix of php and html. These files however end in .ss and therefore netbeans doesnt format and highlight them at all. How do I make netbeans format and highlight all .ss files just as if they where normal html files?

Kind Regards
Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools > Options > Misc > Files

Though I'd also look out for any plugins that may give you some extra functionality for your CMS out of the box... I have one for Drupal for instance. It takes care of any Drupal specific extensions and has a new module wizard.

Comment: cheers mate that worked! On a Mac with Netbeans 6.8 Its Netbeans > Preferences > Misc > Files If anyone else is having the same problem.